# Get name from Google OpenId in yesod-auth

Tags: haskell, openid, yesod

How can I get a user's full name from Google when authenticating with yesod-auth's GoogleEmail backend?  In my app, I'd like to require users enter as little redundant information as possible.

I'm not sure where to start.  Will I need to modify yesod-auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, yesod-auth doesn't currently provide you with enough access to the underlying OpenID response to get that information. I'd be happy to accept a pull request to extend the API in that direction.

Comment: It's not crucial to me right now, but I'll look into extending yesod-auth as a finishing detail.  Thanks for the information.